# ifelse condition with sampling from specific vector element

Tags: r

I have four vectors:

```
a <- sample(1:2,10,replace=T)
b <- sample(1:2,10,replace=T)
c <- sample(4:5,10,replace=T)
d <- sample(4:5,10,replace=T)
```

I would like to compare each element of `c` with its corresponding element in `d` and do the following:

```
ifelse(c>d,a,ifelse(c==d,SAMPLE(a,b),replace=T),b)
```

a: `[1] 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2`

b:  `[1] 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1`

c:  `[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 4 4`

d:  `[1] 4 4 4 5 5 5 4 4 5 4`
In words:

1. if the first element of c is larger than the first element of d: return a
2. if the first element of c is equal to the first element of d choose randomly between a and b
3. if the first element of c is smaller than d return b
4. repeat for each element from 1 to 10.

What I am having trouble with is point 2. How can I tell R to sample only from a given element and not the whole vector:

here's the output I would like to see:

```
sample[1,2], sample[1,1], sample[2,2], b, b, b, a, a,b, sample[2,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a == b` then there isn't really any point making a `sample` right? Because both `a` and `b` are the same? So you would be randomly choosing between the same number?!

I'd just use `pmax` to return the greatest element at each postion:

```
pmax( a , b )
[1] 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2
```

From the help page for `pmax`:

> **`pmax`** and **`pmin`** take one or more vectors (or matrices) as arguments and return a single vector giving the ‘parallel’ maxima (or minima) of the vectors. The first element of the result is the maximum (minimum) of the first elements of all the arguments, the second element of the result is the maximum (minimum) of the second elements of all the arguments and so on.

#### Edit due to new information from OP

Here's one way to do what you want with three vectors (I just wrote this example up and saw you posted something with 4). This approach readily translates to your updated OP, I'll leave you to work out how. When posting data generated through RNG its a good idea to specify the seed so someone can reproduce your vectors.

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- sample( 2 , 10 , repl = T ); b <- sample( 2 , 10 , repl=T ); c <- sample(5 , 10 , repl = T )
#a
#[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2
#b
#[1] 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1
#c
#[1] 2 2 1 1 2 5 3 5 5 1

#  Empty output vector
out <- rep( NA , length( a ) )

#  Fill elements where a does not equal b with the pmax value of a or b
out[ a != b ] <- pmax( a[ a != b ] , b[ a != b ] )

#  Indicies where a == b 
ind <- a == b

#  Fill elements where a == b with a random choice of a or c for that element
set.seed(1)
out[ ind ] <- cbind( a[ind] , c[ind] )[ cbind( seq_len( sum( ind ) ) , sample( 2 , sum( ind ) , repl = TRUE ) ) ]
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 5 3 1 2 2
```

Comment: yes but what if assignment is done from a third vector? say ifelse(a>b ) -> a, ifelse a==b, sample (a,c), c

Comment: @user1984076 but that's not what your post says. It makes no mention anywhere of a third vector. Perhaps you should update your post to include this new information.

Comment: yes I'm sorry I was trying to make it as simple as possible but I was imprecise.. please see my edit

Comment: this is a complicated multiple line solution..I know I wasn't very precise but I was asking for a solution using ifelse() and 1 line. Do you think its not possible to do this with ifelse?

Comment: It's really not that complicated. It's multi-line to illustrate the steps. Importantly, it works and I am fairly sure this multi-line solution is faster than using a single line nested `ifelse`. You are free to wait for other solutions or work it out for yourself.

Comment: yes but this doesn't really do what I was asking for, for example your  code in the 4th line chooses the pmax of a and b, but it should actually select the pmax of and b and then select c or d accordingly

Comment: @user1984076 it does **what you wrote in the first comment under the answer**. You then changed your problem spec again. I'm not spending anymore time on this i'm sorry. You can easily translate what is in this answer to both your original question, your updated question in the comments and then your subsequently updated-updated question. I'm not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am just tinkering, but how about this:

```
pswitch <- function(x,...) diag(sapply(x,switch,...))
pswitch(sign(c-d)+2,b,ifelse(runif(10)>.5,a,b),a)
```